# Cronjob returns an error when running

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron

I have been tasked to run a script from cron, so I have written following cronjob for the script and it output the following mentioned error message.

cronjob

```
#BE housekeeper.sh
* * * * * /product/tools/housekeeper.sh -t BE > /tmp/fileset.out 2>&1
```

fileset.out contain the error message. this is the error message.

```
/bin/sh: /product/tools/housekeeper.sh: Permission denied
```

why does it says permission denied. `user1` can execute the housekeeper script as follows

```
$sh housekeeper.sh -t BE
```

then I checked whether user1 is allowed to run the cronjob. this check also pass. user1 is allowed to run crontab. so what could be the possible error in this case.

```
root      4181     1  0  2011 ?        00:00:00 crond
user1    7648  7564  0 06:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep cron
```

I checked execute rights of the application

```
$ls -ltr

-rw-r----- 1 user1 aapp 11732 May 17 08:55 housekeeper.sh
```

does it says this application is executable

thanks in advance for anyhelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `housekeeper.sh` to have `755` permission (executable)

```
chmod 755 housekeeper.sh
```

Running `sh housekeeper.sh` and `/product/tools/housekeeper.sh` has a slightly difference in the way that doing `sh` calls an executable called `sh` found in the `$PATH` and feed `housekeeper.sh` into it, so you only need read permission on `housekeeper.sh`, but directly running it by doing `/product/tools/housekeeper.sh` would require you to have execute permission (thus the `755`)

EDIT

I see that you have `-rw-r-----` permission, that is quite simply `610`, let me explain a bit

a file has 3 sets of permissions, represented in 3 groups of 3 bits. The first bit means read permission, as in your output, you see `r`, second bit is write permission `w` and third bit (which is not set, is `x`, executable bit). You have 3 sets of that, the first for Owner, Group and then Other, thus you have 9 bits

```
 111 111 111
 VVV VVV VVV
  |   |   |
Owner |   |
    Group |
        Other
```

so `rw-r-----` indicates that the owner has read and write bit, group has read bit, and other has no permission to do anything to this file.

Setting 755 will yield `rwxr-xr-x`, I'll leave it to you to think why :D

Comment: i undated the question after typing ls -ltr for housekeeper.sh. i can not translate the output to check whether it has executable permission. could you help me with that

Comment: BTW: IMHO 0700 (maybe even 0100( ...) is possibly enough. Cron changes user before actually attempting to execute the file.